# Map JSON array to objects array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm testing with a JSON data mock of this format:

```
   [
        {
            "_id": "5ea1c3e2f376f7887032bd44",
            "iso6393": "ara",
            "name": "Arabic"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ea1c3e2f376f7887032bd41",
            "iso6393": "eng",
            "name": "English"
        }
    ]
```

My Angular code injects it into the `Language[]` array. I can access the object and have intelligence about the object in my IDE and pre-transpiling failure:

```
getLanguages(): Promise<Language[]> {
    const url = this.cfgSvc.composeURL(SettingsEnum.LANGS);
    return this.http.get<Language[]>(url).toPromise();
  }
```

Now, the webservice changed and wraps the JSON into a parent "languages" node:

```
{
    "languages": [
        {
            "_id": "5ea1c3e2f376f7887032bd44",
            "iso6393": "ara",
            "name": "Arabic"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ea1c3e2f376f7887032bd41",
            "iso6393": "eng",
            "name": "English"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this wont work any more with my code. How can I strip the `languages` parent node and map the elements to `Language[]` array again?

I failed to implement it with pipe and map. And I don't want to do it with verbose code and constructors on the `Language` object.

Comment: `.then(({ languages }) => languages)`? How exactly did you fail to do this with `pipe` and `map`? Have you updated the generic type of the response body to `{ languages: Language[] }` so TypeScript can help you out?

Comment: Read up on *destructuring*. That's not specific to requests/Angular/TypeScript/RxJS, it's just (newer) JS syntax. The first step here is to update the generic type you're providing to `http.get` to reflect the *actual shape* of the response, the compiler can help to guide you from there.

Comment: Do you actually want to change what `getLanguages` returns a Promise of? My understanding was that you wanted to keep that the same, but the shape of the *response* was changing. A simplified example compiles just fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=10&pln=14&pc=18#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDJxAcwK50ygbwChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpRMBuIgXyKNElkRXRZc+OsmKkANhhx4IdWoJn4A2gF02nIjGwgEYYAHsQyfGAAicMHAA8AFQB8ACgCUtAApQDFYHQh37YiTIUBBg2FDGHl4+EAB0IXQGEgBuEI4E7MhworbOGlzauvpGyNi+AMphMDAu7p7evtaKwhBqAeLBoeHGphZWTdItdE7OsWAAFhAgjunIUkKyouzOyAC8AfNKcnkcREA. Otherwise give a [mre].

Comment: No, thank you. Please [edit] the question if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share the complete solution, which was led by @jonrsharpe. Thanks. I didn't know about destructuring. That will be part of my daily use now!

```
getLanguages(): Promise<Language[]> {
    const url = this.cfgSvc.composeURL(SettingsEnum.LANGS);
    return this.http.get<Languages>(url).toPromise().then(
      {languages} => languages);
  }
```

The arrow function in `then` receives the result of the get request (response body). Since that is the given variable, one may extract from it whatever you want and assign it to variable after the fat arrow. I my case I want to extract every `language` node without the root node `languages`.

```
({languages}) => languages
```

Amazingly concise. This can also be written verbose.

```
({languages: langs}) => { 
     return langs
}
```

Which results in the stripping of the parent node `languages` from the json response, entailing merely the array of `Language`s. In other words, I takes only the value of the `languages` node.

That's why I would not need to change the `Promise<Language[]>` generics of the method signature. However - as @jonrsharpe pointed out correctly - one needs to set the *receiving* generics of the `http.get` to `Languages` to represent the incoming structure.

Destructuring... amazing. Here is a solid tutorial about this new feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIq3qLaHCIs